# If $G$ is a cyclic group of order $d$ with generator $a$, show that $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{d\mathbb{Z}}$ is isomorphic $G$.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

We have to $|G|=d$ and $G=\left<a\right>=\{a^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ by definition of cyclic group.

To show what you are asking, I want to define a function, not necessarily this
$$\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to G \text{ such that } z \mapsto \phi(z)=a^d$$
and use the theorem: Let $\varphi:G \to G'$ be a group homomorphism, then
$$\dfrac{G}{ker(\varphi)} \simeq Im(\varphi)$$

I need your help to define well a function that serves me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Define $\phi (x)=a^x$, for each $x\in\mathbb Z$.